# what is inverse probability all about?

Tags: probability

I just want to know its idea, concept and how it is related to Bayes theorem? how inverse probability is different from other direct probability of event, where we usually find the probability value of event(s)?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit and provide a bit of context? The inverse probability of a random variable X having value x is 1/p(x); that's probably not what you want to hear...?

Answer (score 2):

All the details about direct and inverse probability can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_probability).

Before the mid of the 20th century, *direct probability* was the probability to have a certain observation given the parameters $\theta$. This is equivalent to what we currently call *likelihood* $p(X|\theta)$.
*Inverse probability* was instead the name used for the probability of a parameter $\theta$, given the observation $X$. It got its name from the fact that its aim was to determine *the causes* ($\theta$), given the observation. This is what today we call *posterior probability* $p(\theta|X)$.

Now it should be clear the connection between the *inverse* probability and Bayes theorem.

*Bayes* theorem provides a way to estimate the *posterior* probability, given the *likelihood* and a *prior*. In other terms, it solves the inverse probability problem, given the direct probability model.